# passport.js req.user is returning: 'Promise { false }' - How do I get the current sessions' username?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

In Node.js, I used the passportJS LocalStrategy to authenticate the users. And this function

`req.getAuthenticated()`

Allows me to get whether the current session is authenticated. I also wanted the server to return the username of the current session. To do that, I tried accessing the user property of req.

```
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    let user = req.user.username;
}
```

But it is returning 'undefined'. I continued with...

```
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    console.log(req.user);
}
```

And it says that the req.user is a 'Promise{ false }', for some reason. I, and then tried out

```
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    let user = await req.user;
    console.log(user);
}
```

And it returns 'false'. This is the first time I've worked with the passport.js so I may have set it up wrong because req.user should not return a promise, right? Any suggestions?

FOR MORE INFO: Here is what my passport serialization/deserialization and passport.use functions look like:

Again, the getAuthenticated function works perfectly. When users are logged on, they are authenticated, and when they're not, they're not authenticated. I just can't get the req.user properties.

```
const initialize = (passport, UserCollection, getUserFromUsername, getUserFromId) => {
    const authenticateUser = async (username, password, done) => {
        let user = await getUserFromUsername(UserCollection, username);
        if(user === null){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'The user with that username does not exist in the database.'});
        }
        try{
            if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)){
                return done(null, user);
            }
            else{
                return done(null, false, {message: 'Passwords do not match'});
            }
        }
        catch {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'There was a problem logging you in.'})
        }
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(authenticateUser));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        return done(null, user._id);
    });
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        return done(null, getUserFromId(id));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wait a promise in `deserializeUser`:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        const user = await getUserFromId(id);
        return done(null, user);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This was one of the two problems I had in the code above. The 2nd problem is that I didn't pass the User database model to getUserFromId